# NSButton subclass inside trigger also other class

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I created a subclass of **NSButton** in IB and set the subclass as the custom class for my button. The button works, but in my main file ( **NSObject** ) the " **someMethod** " which is a **IBAction** linked to the same button do not work. What i wanted to do is that " if " the subclass ( **NSButton** ) is clicked, then inside my ( **NSObject** )the someMethod should **exit**, as if it was clicked. But i'm 
lost can't understand why it wont work, please help me out, i'm really lost.

**I'm going give you the whole source code, i have the following code in my .h file:**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>



@interface HoverButton : NSButton
{


    NSTrackingArea *trackingArea;



}



- (void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)theEvent;
- (void)mouseExited:(NSEvent *)theEvent;
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)ev;
- (void)mouseUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent;


@end
```

**And the following code for the .m file:**

```
#import "HoverButton.h"


@implementation HoverButton




- (void)updateTrackingAreas
{
    [super updateTrackingAreas];

    if (trackingArea)
    {
        [self removeTrackingArea:trackingArea];
        [trackingArea release];
    }

    NSTrackingAreaOptions options = NSTrackingInVisibleRect | NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited | NSTrackingActiveInKeyWindow;
    trackingArea = [[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:NSZeroRect options:options owner:self userInfo:nil];
    [self addTrackingArea:trackingArea];



}



- (void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)event
{

    [self setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"1"]];
}

- (void)mouseExited:(NSEvent *)event
{
    [self setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"2"]];
}




- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)ev {

    [self setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"2"]];



}


- (void)mouseUp:(NSEvent *)ev {
    [self setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"1"]];

}
@end
```

**This is the main .h file:**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface Main : NSObject {

}
-(IBAction) someMethod:(id) sender;

@end
```

**and the main .m file**

```
#import "Main.h"

#import "HoverButton.h"

@implementation Main





-(IBAction) someMethod:(id) sender   
{

     NSEvent *SKMouseDown; //Mouse down events

     HoverButton *frac = [[HoverButton alloc] init];

    [frac mouseDown: SKMouseDown];


    exit(0); // < --- does not work, someMethod docent work.


}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly, u like to call back parent class from event inside subclass of nsbutton.
It can be done for different manner:

- add @property (assign) Main *delegate
- after allocate HoverButton set frac.delegate = self;

inside any methods where u like to be calling delegate call:
 if (delegate && [delegate performSelector:@selector(someMethod:)]) {
    [delegate someMethod:self];
}

that' all and working fine for both platforms

Comment: could you post whole source code of your edit, to show? how you implant that